# Reverse Sorting with IComparable

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparable

I have code like this -

```
List<User> users;
protected class User : IComparable<User>
{
    public string name;
    public string email;
    public decimal total;
    public string address;
    public string company;
    public string origin;
    public int CompareTo(User b)
    {
        return this.total.CompareTo(b.total);

    }
}
```

For a table that is sorted by the number of points a user has. It sorts in ascending order, but need to change it to descending order. It uses `users.Sort()`, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it sort in reverse order.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to reverse the order, just reverse the comparison:

```
public int CompareTo(User b)
{
    return b.total.CompareTo(this.total);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If your `User` class can be changed to sort in reverse order, you can try other answers which suggests modifying `CompareTo` method. Otherwise try the following.

```
users.Sort();//Sort normally
users.Sort((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));//Reverse sort
```

Answer (score 3):

Just reverse the parameters in your comparison. So instead of:

```
return this.total.CompareTo(b.total);
```

Just do:

```
return b.total.CompareTo(this.total);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int CompareTo(User b)
{
    return this.total.CompareTo(b.total) * -1;

}
```

Comment: Edge case problem here! CompareTo doesn't limit range of return values, and due to 2s complement numbers and overflow we have the situation where (Int32.MinValue * -1 == int32.MinValue) which could cause a problem.